# Is it OK to change __name__ of a function to use as description?

Tags: python

I want to test a couple of similar functions and would like to have a neater output (in a plot) than the actual variable name. Is this what '**name**' is intended for or are there technical reasons not to do this?

An example would be

```
def add2(x):
    return x + 2

add2.__name__ = 'Add 2'

test(add2)
```

Comment: What does your test function does exactly?

Comment: Friendly descriptions are what docstrings are for. Changing the `__name__` will break all sorts of things (in particularly, pickleability of the function, which relies on introspecting the name); you're trying to impose "pretty" names on things with programmatic meaning, and it will eventually hurt you. If you want a display function to use a friendly name, pass it an alternate string and use that.

Comment: Please don't do this. If you want a nicer description put it into the docstring.

Comment: Of course, you're also free to add any attribute you want to your functions. Eg, `add2.longname = 'Add 2'`

Comment: @ShadowRanger actually docstrings are for documentation...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: The first line of every docstring, by convention, is usually a friendly description of the function. I'm not saying it would necessarily work for an axis label like this person wants, but it's a place where arbitrary text is okay. Renaming a function in its metadata is not such a place.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I wholefully agree that rebinding the function's `__name__` is not the right solution and that _for this use case_ using the docstring instead is a lesser evil - but here I'd still rather use a custom attribute instead and keep the docstring for it's intended use ;)

Comment: Another option is to do a little processing on your function names when you display them. Eg, `add_2.__name__.replace('_', ' ').title()`. But my preference is for a custom attribute.